# How to Consume Yahoo Finance API in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to learn Django and built a small app that contains a list of companies with some general info for each of them.  The home page shows a list of all companies and then a user can click on the company name to see more info.  I'm now trying figure out how APIs are consumed in Django by using Yahoo Finance to get some stock data about the company and display it on the page. (I've used the yahoo-finance package multiple times in Python and it's pretty straight forward, which is why I've stared with this). I don't need to save the data to a database (unless that's the only way), I simply want to display it.

I've pip installed the packaged and added it to the APPS in the settings.py file.

Then in my views.py I've added the yahoo-finance dependencies and tried to work in the API in the code below.  Then in the template I'm trying to use {{ mkt_cap }}.  Doing it this way I'm getting a YQLResponseMalformedError.  I realize this may not be the correct way to go about it, but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Company, Articles, Transcripts, TranscriptDetails
from yahoo_finance import Share
import json

class CompanyDetails(generic.DetailView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'company_details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        context = super(CompanyDetails, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['articles'] = Articles.objects.filter(company_id=pk).order_by('-date')
        context['company'] = Company.objects.get(id=pk)
        context['transcripts'] = Transcripts.objects.filter(company_id=pk).order_by('-date')
        # Get Yahoo API data
        stock_symbol = Company.objects.filter(id=pk).values_list('stock_symbol', flat=True)
        data = Share(stock_symbol)
        data = json.load(data)
        context['mkt_cap'] = data

        return context
```

**EDIT**

Here's the final code in case someone else has a similar question.  I've kept all of the API calls in the View and created a dictionary to pass them to the template.

```
class CompanyDetails(generic.DetailView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'company_details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        context = super(CompanyDetails, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['articles'] = Articles.objects.filter(company_id=pk).order_by('-date')
        context['transcripts'] = Transcripts.objects.filter(company_id=pk).order_by('-date')
        # Get Yahoo API data
        stock_symbol = self.object.stock_symbol
        data = Share(stock_symbol)
        stock_open = data.get_open()
        year_range = data.get_year_range()
        fifty_day_moving_average = data.get_50day_moving_avg()
        market_cap = data.get_market_cap()

        yahoo_finance = dict()
        yahoo_finance['stock_open'] = stock_open
        yahoo_finance['year_range'] = year_range
        yahoo_finance['fifty_day_moving_average'] = fifty_day_moving_average
        yahoo_finance['market_cap'] = market_cap
        context['yahoo_finance'] = yahoo_finance

        return context
```

Then in the template to access these I similar use the following:

```
{{ yahoo_finance.stock_open }}
{{ yahoo_finance.year_range }}
{{ yahoo_finance.fifty_day_moving_average }}
{{ yahoo_finance.market_cap }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the market cap, you can just do

```
data = Share(stock_symbol)
market_cap = data.get_market_cap()
context['mkt_cap'] = market_cap
```

It looks `data` is a `yahoo_finance.Share` object that you can use directly. You can look inside with `data.__dict__` but should probably just use the methods documented in the API.

Alternatively, you can likely just pass `data` directly into the template and use `{{data.get_market_cap}}`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was looking for.  Passing the data object and then calling the API inside the template is an added bonus I wasn't aware I could do.  I prefer to keep the API requests in the View though so I just created a dictionary to add in additional requests there.

Answer (score 1):

The `values_list` method returns a list. You are passing this to `Share`, which expects a string.

The simplest fix would be to change it to:

```
stock_symbol = Company.objects.filter(id=pk).values_list('stock_symbol', flat=True)[0]
data = Share(stock_symbol)
```

However, you don't have to fetch the company from the database at all -- the `DetailView` does this for you. Therefore, you can use `self.object.stock_symbol` to get the stock symbol

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CompanyDetails, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['articles'] = Articles.objects.filter(company=self.object).order_by('-date')
    context['transcripts'] = Transcripts.objects.filter(company=self.object).order_by('-date')
    # Get Yahoo API data
    stock_symbol = self.object.stock_symbol
    data = Share(stock_symbol)
    data = json.load(data)
    context['mkt_cap'] = data

    return context
```

Comment: This answer is helpful as it points out that I don't need the "  context['company'] " line of code, however I selected @user6731765 as the accepted answer because it also corrected the API call which appears as if it was incorrect.